# Make child views or Text view scroll behind SVG shape with transparent background in react-native

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am trying to get the text or any other child views inside the scrollview to appear behind the SVG shape which is transparent, the following SVG shape code in react-native:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import  { Path, G, Svg, Rect } from 'react-native-svg'

const shapes = {
    pathOne: "M380.279 107.377C380.279 107.377 295.739 13.1031 187.625 107.25C79.5108 201.397 -1.97128 107.125 -1.97128 107.125L-1.89778 1.07516e-06L380.353 0.252415L380.279 107.377Z",
}


export class WaveShape extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {

    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen")

    return (
        <Svg width="357" height="187" viewBox="-1 -1 375 187">
            <Path fill="red" fillOpacity={0.5} d={shapes.pathOne}></Path>
        </Svg>
    );
  }
}
```

The component where I am trying to get SVG shape to appear:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
  } from 'react-native';

  import {
    Header,
    LearnMoreLinks,
    Colors,
    DebugInstructions,
    ReloadInstructions,
  } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { WaveShape } from '../components/WaveShape';

export class Main extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
      header: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <SafeAreaView>
            <WaveShape></WaveShape>
            <ScrollView
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                style={styles.scrollView}>
                {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
                <View style={styles.engine}>
                    <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
                </View>
                )}
                <View style={styles.body}>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                    screen and then come back to see your edits.
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    <ReloadInstructions />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    <DebugInstructions />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    Read the docs to discover what to do next:
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <LearnMoreLinks />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    engine: {
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
    },
    body: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    },
    sectionContainer: {
      marginTop: 32,
      paddingHorizontal: 24,
    },
    sectionTitle: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: '600',
      color: Colors.black,
    },
    sectionDescription: {
      marginTop: 8,
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: '400',
      color: Colors.dark,
    },
    highlight: {
      fontWeight: '700',
    },
    footer: {
      color: Colors.dark,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: '600',
      padding: 4,
      paddingRight: 12,
      textAlign: 'right',
    },
  });
```

This is what I am getting as a result:

[image]

Now my goal is to make child views or text appear behind the wave shape path and not the viewbox that contains the path of the SVG.

Comment: So you're saying that the text should be visible in the SVG picture?

Comment: Yes, could be any child views that are inside the scrollview it should appear behind the SVG shape that is drawn inside the SVG viewbox if it has a transparent background.

Comment: You can use `zIndex`

Comment: for which view?

Comment: Using zIndex, you might want to make a text view visible on the SVG view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [hong develop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11212074/hong-develop) I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing the following:

The code for the SVG shape:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import  { Path, G, Svg, Rect } from 'react-native-svg'

const shapes = {
    pathOne: "M380.279 107.377C380.279 107.377 295.739 13.1031 187.625 107.25C79.5108 201.397 -1.97128 107.125 -1.97128 107.125L-1.89778 1.07516e-06L380.353 0.252415L380.279 107.377Z",
}


export class WaveShape extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {

    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen")
    const { style, ...props } = this.props

    return (
        <Svg style={[style]} {...props} width="357" height="187" viewBox="-1 -1 375 187">
            <Path fill="red" fillOpacity={0.5} d={shapes.pathOne}></Path>
        </Svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Code where I am calling SVG shape:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
  } from 'react-native';

  import {
    Header,
    LearnMoreLinks,
    Colors,
    DebugInstructions,
    ReloadInstructions,
  } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { WaveShape } from '../components/WaveShape';

export class Main extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
      header: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <SafeAreaView>
            <WaveShape style={{ position: "absolute" ,top: 0, zIndex: 1 }}></WaveShape>
            <ScrollView
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                style={styles.scrollView}>
                <View style={{ paddingTop: "45%" }}></View>
                {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
                <View style={styles.engine}>
                    <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
                </View>
                )}
                <View style={styles.body}>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                    screen and then come back to see your edits.
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    <ReloadInstructions />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    <DebugInstructions />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                    Read the docs to discover what to do next:
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <LearnMoreLinks />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    engine: {
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
    },
    body: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    },
    sectionContainer: {
      marginTop: 32,
      paddingHorizontal: 24,
    },
    sectionTitle: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: '600',
      color: Colors.black,
    },
    sectionDescription: {
      marginTop: 8,
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: '400',
      color: Colors.dark,
    },
    highlight: {
      fontWeight: '700',
    },
    footer: {
      color: Colors.dark,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: '600',
      padding: 4,
      paddingRight: 12,
      textAlign: 'right',
    },
  });
```

Result:

[image]